# How do I randomly select a generic type without repetitions

Tags: java, arrays, generics, random

I have a coding assignment which I'm about 90% of the way through. The task is to randomly assign seats to a randomly selected person. I am having troubles with my drawItem() method in the Generic class, as I am supposed to eliminate it so the same number or person name doesn't repeat when being drawn.

The assignment description says: drawItem() – to randomly select an object from the box and return it, as well as eliminating it from the box (if the box is empty return null)...

*Any help with the eliminating the object is greatly appreciated!!* I have been stuck on this part of the assignment for too long now.

Here is my GenericDriver class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Generic<String> myStringBox = new Generic<String>();

        // use the .add() function to add slips of papers with names on
        // them to fill the box
        myStringBox.add("Person 1");
        myStringBox.add("Person 2");
        myStringBox.add("Person 3");
        myStringBox.add("Person 4");
        myStringBox.add("Person 5");
        System.out.println("... names are being added!");

        Generic<Integer> myIntegerStack = new Generic<Integer>();
        // use the .add() function to add the integer slips of paper to the box
        myIntegerStack.add(1);
        myIntegerStack.add(2);
        myIntegerStack.add(3);
        myIntegerStack.add(4);
        myIntegerStack.add(5);
        System.out.println("... numbers are being added!");

        System.out.println("..... Generating which seat a person will occupy .....\n");

        System.out.println("First draw: " + myStringBox.drawItem()
            + " will occupy seat number: " + myIntegerStack.drawItem());

        System.out.println("Second draw: " + myStringBox.drawItem()
            + " will occupy seat number: " + myIntegerStack.drawItem());

        System.out.println("Third draw: " + myStringBox.drawItem()
            + " will occupy seat number: " + myIntegerStack.drawItem());

        System.out.println("Fourth draw: " + myStringBox.drawItem()
            + " will occupy seat number: " + myIntegerStack.drawItem());

        System.out.println("Fifth draw: " + myStringBox.drawItem()
            + " will occupy seat number: " + myIntegerStack.drawItem());

    }

}
```

Here is my Generic class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public class Generic<T> {

    // creating an array
    T[] item;
    // count of the object's size
    int size;

    //generic constructor that will initilize the items in the box
    Generic (){
        item = (T[]) new Object[5];
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        item[size] = t;
        size++;
    }

    Random randomDraw = new Random();

    public T drawItem() {
        return item[randomDraw.nextInt(item.length)];
    }

    public String toString(){
        return Arrays.toString(item);
    }
```

Here is a sample output to visualize what I mean:

```
..... Generating which seat a person will occupy .....

First draw: Person 4 will occupy seat number: 1
Second draw: Person 5 will occupy seat number: 1
Third draw: Person 2 will occupy seat number: 1
Fourth draw: Person 3 will occupy seat number: 3
Fifth draw: Person 1 will occupy seat number: 5
```

Comment: You do not need to randomize the seats, just pick random people for seats from 1 to 5. It is also questionable if you need this much code, all you need is an array of length 5 with number numbers in it. Try a different approach, a Set that already picked numbers and a while loop should help you to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawItem() should remove the item from the underlying array so it's not chosen again. It literally says to remove the item and return it or return null if the array is empty.

This should do it for you. Generic also uses List of T instead of array. If this isn't possible let me know.

```java
    public static class Generic<T> {

        Random random = new Random();

        List<T> items;

        public Generic(List<T> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public Generic(T... items) {
            this(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items)));
        }

        public void add(T t) {
            items.add(t);
        }

        public T drawItem() {
            if (items.size() <= 0) {
                return null;
            }
            int index = random.nextInt(items.size());

            return items.remove(index);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return items.toString();
        }
    }
```

Test

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<String> myStringBox = new Generic<>("Person 0", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4");

        Generic<Integer> myIntegerStack = new Generic<>(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);

        for (int index = 0; index < myStringBox.items.size(); index++) {
            String person = myStringBox.drawItem();

            int seat = myIntegerStack.drawItem();

            System.out.println(String.format("%s draw: %s will occupy seat %s.",
                    (index + 1), person, seat));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
1 draw: Person 4 will occupy seat 1.
2 draw: Person 0 will occupy seat 3.
3 draw: Person 1 will occupy seat 4.
4 draw: Person 3 will occupy seat 0.
5 draw: Person 2 will occupy seat 2.
```

Comment: Hey Jason, thanks for the reply, this helps a lot! I'm allowed to use lists, but I haven't used streams yet ie: IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed().forEach(index -> ... is there a more beginner-friendly way of writing this?

Comment: Yeah absolutely. That's just a prettier (IMO) for-loop. I'll edit it for you.

Comment: Ahh, I see how concise the IntStream for-loop was... something for me to learn about! Thank you Jason.

Comment: No worries! Anytime :)